# Refresh LWC when related list is updated or related file is deleted

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, related-list, lightning-message-service, lightning-message-channel

I have a custom LWC on a record detail page. This LWC displays files related to the record. I cannot use the standard Files related list because I only want to show files of type jpg, jpeg and png.

To mimic the standard Files related list, in my custom LWC when I click an image I'm calling the NavigationMixin with 'standard__namedPage' and 'filePreview'. This will open the image preview just like how it would on a standard Files related list. It also shows options like 'Edit File Details' and 'Delete File'.

The issue is when I click on Delete File, it does successfully delete the file but my LWC is not updated. Only when I manually refresh the browser, does the image disappear from my LWC. But I noticed that whenever I delete the file, all other standard related lists are getting automatically refreshed because I see the loading spinner on each of them.

This means that there is something that is telling those related lists that a file associated with their parent record was deleted. I want even my custom LWC to receive that "standard message?" so that I can re-render my LWC.

Answer (score 2):

If you loaded the files using @wire, you could use [refresh apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching) functionality to refresh the list every time you delete the file.